# Chrome.storage.local get wrong value

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to load content from chrome.storage.local but it doesn't work (it always return the same result, [object OBJECT]).
This is my code :

```
    function load()
{
    var loginC = "";
    chrome.storage.local.get('loginC', function(result){
    loginC = result;
        if (loginC != "") {
            document.getElementById("login").value = loginC;
        }
    });

    var passC = "";
    chrome.storage.local.get('passC', function(result){
    passC = result;
        if (passC != "") {
            document.getElementById("pass").value = passC;
        }
    });
}

load();
```

Comment: Take a closer look at the documentation of [`chrome.storage.local.get`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#method-StorageArea-get)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#method-StorageArea-get) states, the callback receives an object containing the results:

> The callback parameter should be a function that looks like this:
>
> `function(object items) {...};`
>
> `object`  `items`
>
> Object with items in their key-value mappings.

It is done in this way, because one `get` operation can retrieve more than one value.

So in general, the code should look like this:

```
chrome.storage.local.get('keyName', function(result) {
  /* use result.keyName */
});
```

And your code can be simplified to this:

```
chrome.storage.local.get(['loginC', 'passC'], function(result) {
    if (result.loginC) { // Will catch both "" and undefined
        document.getElementById("login").value = result.loginC;
    }
    if (result.passC) {
        document.getElementById("pass").value = result.passC;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `get` method returns an object in the format `{loginC: /*..*/ }` for the `result` variable. Use `result.loginC` and `result.passC` to get the value.